# Deactivate default aria settings in Ag-grid table

Tags: accessibility, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

Hi i'm trying to customize the aria labels in an application but screen reader is reading the position where we are in the table.
[Aria-labels to deactivate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WJFp.jpg)
So I would like to know if it's possible to deactivate this functionality, and if it's possible just for one cell

I tried to create a custom cell with a cell rendering for customized the aria label in each cell, but the table has his own properties for the screen reader by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Programmatically, you should not attempt to turn off the table cell coordinates.  That's not something you should decide.  It's the **user's** choice whether they want to hear the table coordinates.

If you don't want to hear them, you can bring up the NVDA settings and go to the "Document Formatting" category (in the left panel) then scroll down the right panel to "Table information" and uncheck the "Cell coordinates" checkbox.

[image: NVDA table settings]